# How to understand ‘JSXElementConstructor<any> = string’？

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In react, the definition of type ‘ReactElement’ is:

```
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
    type: T;
    props: P;
    key: Key | null;
}
```

But I cannot understand what ‘JSXElementConstructor = string’ means.

The type of `JSXElementConstructor`  is:

```
type JSXElementConstructor<P> =
    | ((props: P) => ReactElement<any, any> | null)
    | (new (props: P) => Component<any, any>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of `T` : `T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string`.

`T` here can be either `string` or `JSXElementConstructor<any>` and the default value is `string`.

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer is a little bit off.
the default value isn't just `string` it's `string | JSXElementConstructor<any>`

You can think of it as follows:
T is any type that extends `string | JSXElementConstructor<any>` and if T isn't provided, then it is the type `string | JSXElementConstructor<any>` itself.